# i cannot get the complete html code using my program

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using jsoup to get the html code from a website. but it does not return complete code. A lot of code is missing that I require. I have tried using `.maxBodySize(0)`, `.timeout(600000)`, `.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0")`, but it does not seem to make a difference.

```
Document doc;
try  {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
        .maxBodySize(0)
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0")
        .timeout(600000).get();
}
catch (IOException e){
    doc = null;
}
System.out.println(doc);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you maybe tell us what it is you're trying to scrape? It's hard to help with this kind of question if the input is unknown.

Comment: When you only want to get code I would recommend to use an HTTP Client and not Jsoup

Comment: i am trying to get the links from a url https://www.horriblesubs.info

Answer (score -1):

Try to write the output in file instead of console. I have face same situation and I resolved it with using file.